# Prove if $4$ kinds of series either converge or diverge.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

[image]

I summed up $4$ kinds of series that I am having trouble solving.
It seems like for the first one, the limit in infinity is - infinity which means it diverges.

The limit when $x \to \infty$ in 2 is $0$, so I think it converges.

Same goes for 3.

And I actually have no idea what I should do in 4.

So basiclly i'm stuck.

Comment: It will be better if you use Mathjax and type these questions instead of posting a picture.

Answer (score 1):

For the first two, as $n \to \infty, \frac 1n \to 0$, so $\sin \frac in \approx \frac 1n \text {and }e^{\frac 1n} \approx (1+\frac 1n)$  For the third you should know that exponentials dominate over polynomials.  For the last, you are expected to plug in Stirling's formula for the factorials and see what comes out.